# Mongoose Post request still works when a required field is missing

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a user model which looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({

    fullName: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Moving forward, my controller function looks like this:

```
exports.register = (req, res) => {
    
    const email = req.body.email
    const name = req.body.fullName

    bcrypt
        .hash(password, 12)
        .then(hashedPassword => {
            const user = new User({
                email: email,
                password: hashedPassword,
                name: name
            })
            return user.save()
        })
        .then(createdUser => {
            res.status(201).json({ message: "user creared", userData: createdUser })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if(!err.statusCode) {
                err.statusCode = 500
            }
            next(err)
        })
}
```

However, when I go to Postman and create the user, even though the fullName field is required, no error is thrown if the fullName field does not exist in the payload.

payload:

```
{
  "email": "john@example.com",
  "number": "119299928",
  "password": "encrypted password",
  "status": "active",
  "role": "administrator"
}
```

I would expect an exception to be thrown if a field is required, but the user actually gets created.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `require: true`, to `required: true`, at the schema delcaration.